# Recalculating subview sizes on rotation in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uipopovercontroller

I have a method I call to calculate the sizes of a bunch of labels I have in a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass, which is in a `UIPopoverController`.  When the user rotates the device, I need to recalculate the sizes, and then have the table re-drawn to use the new sizes.  Every method I've tried to detect the rotation is either depreciated, doesn't get called, or doesn't get called at the right time.  Is there a method that will automatically get called when the device is rotated that I can recalculate my sizes in?

---

Edit: What I have tried and why it doesn't work:

- `shouldAutorotate` - doesn't get called - apparently depreciated.
- `layoutSubviews` - gets called, but if I try to `[self.tableView reloadData]` in here, I get stuck in an infinite loop
- `NSNotificationCenter` observer for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` - Gets called before my controller knows it's new dimensions, so I cannot recalculate my sizes here
- `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]` in `layoutSubviews` - doesn't prompt re-drawing of table.
- `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` - doesn't get called - apparently depreciated.

---

Edit 2: More details on what I'm trying to do

I'm trying to imitate a "rows-and-columns" style table, and line up the labels to imitate the columns.  When I recalculate the sizes, I loop through all the rows of the table, then through each "column" in that row.  I get the width of each column, and keep track of the largest width in all the rows for each column.  Then I manipulate the spacing between widths and the font sizes to get it so that if any row has the widest label in every column, it will still fit on the screen.

Comment: mind sharing which methods did you tried ? shouldAutorotate is deprecated.

Comment: @ChrisH: I can put it there, but if I try to `[self.tableView reloadTable];` there, I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: check Configuring the View Rotation Settings section in UIViewcontroller and which of them you have tried https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods

Comment: @KunalBalani he said the labels he needs to size are in a custom cell.

Comment: @GeneralMike you shouldn't be calling `layoutSubviews` yourself. I was suggesting you calculate your label sizes inside the `layoutSubviews` method of your custom cell.

Comment: @ChrisH: yeah, I know.  It looks like when the device is rotated, the cells are not being re-drawn on their own, so I need to manually call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.  However, I think `[self.tableView reloadData]` calls `layoutSubviews`, so if I call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `layoutSubviews` I get trapped in an infinite loop.

Comment: All you should be doing in layoutSubviews is your label work. Telling the tableView to reload in that method will certainly cause a permanent loop.

Comment: @ChrisH: oh, `layoutSubviews` on the cell - I misread what you were intending at first.  See Edit 2: to my OP.  I think that since it is very unlikely that any given row will have the widest width for each and every column, I need to do these size calculations on my view controller, and not just on my cell.

Comment: did you tried    [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]

Comment: @KunalBalani: I just tried it, it doesn't look like calling `setNeedsDisplay` redraws the table.

Comment: Seems like using the correct autoresizingmask or autolayout would fix this for you. As far as I can tell Apple is trying to move us away from detecting rotation as a means to laying out views.

Comment: try suing autoreisingmask for width and it should work without any hassle.

Comment: @ChrisH: I thought of that, but if I try doing this with just autolayout/autoresizingmask, it's just going to space things for a given row, and the next row could be spaced totally differently, correct?  The widths of some of the columns could vary greatly between rows, and I have many columns, so if I just use autolayout, the last columns of each row will pretty much never be straight.

Comment: My Suggestion is to use two custom cells. One for Portrait and other for Landscape. Just load the cell according to orientation and do not use reuseidentifier cells.

Comment: @RahulVyas: A good suggestion.  But as I said, I am displaying this table in a popover - I set it's `myController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MAX,440);`, so that it will always take up the whole width of the screen and show 10 rows at a time.  When I am calculating my sizes, I use `self.tableview.contentSize.width` to get the width of the cell, but that only gives me the width in the current orientation.  If I make two different custom cells, how would I get the width before it rotates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to rely on the actual rendered UILabels inside of your cell to calculate your "column" widths. Do this instead:

1. Implement a method called `calculateColumnWidthsForInterfaceOrientation:` that takes an `UIInterfaceOrientation`. In that method, check if the requested orientation is portrait or landscape using `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)`. Then, based on the orientation go through the data you want to display in your labels and find the widest column widths using NSString's `sizeWithAttributes:` method (or one of its derivatives). Caches those values in an array or something.
2. Add a method like `setColumnWidths:` to your custom table view cell that takes the desired column widths.
3. In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, retrieve the cached column widths and set it on the cell using the `setColumnWidths:` method.
4. In your cell, layout the labels using the column widths you just set.
5. In your view controller, implement `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`. Inside of it, call `calculateColumnWidthsForInterfaceOrientation:` with the given orientation and after that call `[self.tableView reloadData]`.
6. Finally, in `viewDidLoad`, call `[self calculateColumnWidthsForInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation]` to do the initial setup of your data before the first rotation.

That should do the trick.

**Update:**
The total width of your **cell** should be equal to the total width of your **table view**. That can be managed with auto-layout or by other means. That size will be reflected in the cell's frame size.

**Update 2:**
Since we are talking about a **popover**, you could maybe simply dismiss the popover in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and then display it again with your new desired dimensions after the rotation is done in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`.

Comment: Most of this is what I'm already doing.  `sizeWithFont:` has been depreciated, which is why I need to render `UILabels` to calculate my column widths.  How do I calculate the total width of the cell depending on the orientation (see my response to RahulVyas's comment on my OP).  Also, `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is another one of the rotation methods that have been depreciated, so I'm back to my original question of "how do I detect the rotation".  I'll add `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` to the list of things that doesn't work in my OP.

Comment: You are right about the `sizeWithFont:` method: I've changed it to `sizeWithAttributes:`. I don't think `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` is deprecated, however. I couldn't find anything in the docs or the headers. I've added another update to my answer.

Comment: I tried `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` and put a stopper on it - it doesn't get called (on the Simulator at least - so maybe this is a simulator-only bug?).

Comment: Concerning your update: I'm currently using `self.tableView.contentSize.width`, but that only returns the width in the current orientation.  How would I get the width ahead of time if the orientation were to change?

Comment: What happens when you rotate? Don't popovers disappear and re-appear when you rotate the device? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859842/issue-with-positioning-of-pop-over-view/3859872#3859872 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1694/_index.html

Comment: HA! Dismissing and re-showing the popover worked.  Good idea.

Answer (score 1):

in layoutSubviews try to recalculate subview one cell

for example in CustomCell.m

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{

UIViewController *viewController = (id)[(AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window].rootViewController;

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(viewController.interfaceOrientation))
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
else
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

}

Comment: Hm, I don't think this is anything close to what I'm looking for.  Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Auto Layout to define your tableView and cells?  Using the proper constraints in conjunction with `updateConstraints` to update the cell layout upon device rotation should help.  With this approach you can set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` of each "column's" label and define constraints to handle the appropriate horizontal padding regardless or orientation.

Also, if using iOS 7 then you should implement `popoverController:willRepositionPopoverToRect:inView:` to handle layout of your subviews upon rotation unless you presented the popover from a bar button item.  I recommend reviewing [UIPopoverController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverController)